# Debugging MMU activation in eclipse and gdb

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, mmu

I try to debug the initialization of my processor (EP7312 of Cirrus Logic, ARM7) using a j-link probe of segger, eclipse with CDT plugin and yagarto.

Everything works fine until I activate the MMU of the processor. After that, the debugger is completely lost.

I'm aware that debuggers can lose track of the program counter when the MMU is activated and I tried to set a break point after the MMU activation to run the program from here, but the debugger is still lost.

Does anyone know a way to configure eclipse so it can handle the passage from MMU not activated to MMU activated?

Version of eclipse : 20090920-1017
Version of gnu : Sourcery 7.2.50

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with eclipse, but you should be able to use the `**add-symbol-file**' gdb command to giving it the kernel, and the address of the text section for the kernel after mmu activation.